# Encountered "INSERT" at character 1, but expected: ["DELETE", "SELECT", "UPDATE"]

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, openjpa

I have an insert JPA named query as below. When I try to execute it from my DAO using enity manger I am getting the below error. I am using Apache OpenJPA, I could not identify the root cause of this issue. I cannot use the persist method because of the complexity of my domain object.

**Encountered "INSERT" at character 1, but expected: ["DELETE", "SELECT", "UPDATE"].**

```
@NamedQuery(
 name=IuaPersistenceConstants.QUERY_INSERT_AGREEMENT_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT,
 query="INSERT INTO AgreementAcknowledgement agrackn VALUES agrackn.id.agrmntCntntUrl = :agrmntCntntUrl, agrackn.id.prvsndUserSqn = :prvsndUserSqn, agrackn.id.prvsnUserEffD = :userEffDate, " +
 "agrackn.id.agrmntacknEffD = :agrmntacknEffD, agrackn.acknExpD = :acknExpD, agrackn.crtTs = :crtTs, agrackn.crtUidC = :crtUidC, agrackn.lstUpdtTs = :lstUpdtTs, agrackn.lstUpdtUidC = :lstUpdtUidC")


Query ackQuery =getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(IuaPersistenceConstants.QUERY_INSERT_AGREEMENT_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT);
 ackQuery.setParameter("agrmntCntntUrl", agreementDO.getAgreementURL());
 ackQuery.setParameter("agrmntacknEffD", agreementDO.getAgreementEffDate());
 ackQuery.setParameter("acknExpD", agreementDO.getAgreementExpDate());
 ackQuery.setParameter("prvsndUserSqn", userDO.getUserSequence());
 ackQuery.setParameter("userEffDate", userDO.getUserEffDate());
 ackQuery.setParameter("crtTs", new Date());
 ackQuery.setParameter("crtUidC", "WS");
 ackQuery.setParameter("lstUpdtTs", new Date());
 ackQuery.setParameter("lstUpdtUidC", "WS");
 ackQuery.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenJPA [doesn't seem to support JPQL "INSERT" queries](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.4.0/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_overview_query.html). But then that is not surprising since JPA DOES NOT define INSERT queries. It defines SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE queries and that is all. See the JPA spec. This is not SQL.

Comment: then how to insert the record when my domain object is very complex? I have so many OneToMany and ManyToOne members in the domain. Building the domain with all those details is very difficult. If I could write a query then it would be easy

Comment: The JPA implementation caters for INSERTs when you call persist. YOU don't do the INSERTs. ANy JPA tutorial would tell you this

Comment: I understand the persist method. But building the domain object with my limited data is very difficult. For example, I have AgreementAcknolodgement.java domain object which has one to many mappings to Agreement.java and User.java/UserRole.java and all that stuff.